# wrapfig and \hrulefill not as expected

Tags: wrapfigure

My document has a number of `\hrulefill` for a student to write about a picture which is inset using the `wrapfig` package.

However, the rules underneath the figure don't extend far enough-as if the figure keeps on extending downward: [image: creative writing]
When I replace the rules with any text, the `wrapfig` works fine.  It is just the `\hrulefill` that doesn't behave.

How do I fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\parskip}{8ex}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{document} 
\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \framebox(5,5)[c]{some picture}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wrapfig has a problem with anything which takes more space than \baselineskip per line of text.  You can  terminate the wrapping using \WFclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the optional argument of `wrapfig` which sets the number of shortlines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\parskip}{8ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
 \centering
    \framebox(5,5)[c]{some picture}
\end{wrapfigure}


\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit* : A more automatic solution can be obtained with the plain TeX macro package `insbox`. The `\InsertBoxR`  command has to be inserted before a paragraph begins. It takes two mandatory arguments: the number of untouched lines before  the object in the box is inserted, and the inserted object. As it may happen TeX gets a wrong box height, an optional argument can be use (at the *end* of the command, which is the number of supplementary shorter lines. Here is a demo with a real graphic file:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \parskip = 8ex
     \setlength{\parskip}{8ex}
     \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \input{insbox.tex}

    \begin{document}

    \hrulefill

    \hrulefill

\vspace*{\parskip}
\InsertBoxR{0}{\parbox[t]{0.48\linewidth}{\centering
\includegraphics{pepe-le-pew2}}}%

   \hrulefill

    \hrulefill

    \hrulefill

    \hrulefill

    \hrulefill

    \hrulefill

    \hrulefill

    \hrulefill

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Either this solution or the use of \WFclear  (@John Kormylo) requires me to determine the height of the figure in terms of lines.  Unfortunate this is not automatic, but at least for me that's not an issue.

Comment: @Tim: I've added another, more automatic solution.